# Make pipe fd return true for is_atty() in child process

Tags: c, terminal, posix

I'm creating some pipes and handing it over to fork()/exec()'d child process as stdout and stderr FDs. But the child program doesn't output ANSI colours.

For e.g., the `gcc` command can output diagnostics with colours. But when I create it as a child of my program and hand over the piped FDs it doesn't send generate colours.

With a bit of snooping around, I found it tests `isatty(STDERR_FILENO)` and doesn't send ANSI colour codes when it returns false. Is there a way I can make my pipes be treated as TTYs in child process?

P.S. Also, please not I'm aware of `unbuffer` shell command which was recommended for similar question. I am looking for C/POSIX API solution that's portable across unices. Not just Linux.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There are two answers to your question, the direct answer and the answer to your XY problem. First, the latter. Generally, programs that can output color/formatting suitable for a terminal, or plain text, choose their *default* based on `isatty`, but let you pass an explicit option to enable or disable it. For GCC, this is `-fdiagnostics-color=always`. This is almost surely what you should be using.

But to answer your original question, the way to do this is not to use a pipe but instead a pseudo-tty (pty). The POSIX interfaces to do this are `posix_openpt`, `grantpt`, `unlockpt`, and `ptsname` (to get the name of the device to open). But there's a much nicer non-standardized interface, `openpty`, that does it all for you in one call, and an accompanying `forkpty` that automatically forks and connects the child's stdin/out/err up to it. I would use one of these if available (they're available on glibc and musl on Linux systems, and on most/all BSD systems).

Comment: Thanks, this is exactly what I was looking for. I was looking for POSIX only solution because I want my application to work on some lesser known BSDs. Seems like forkpty is pretty common even in *BSD systems. Thanks again.

Answer (score 0):

Short answer is no.   Longer answer is that rather than a pipe, you could setup a pseudo-tty, and run a command in it which captures the compilers output.   That is a lot of work.  *Man 7 pty* for a detailed description.

You could take a different approach, and define your own mapping of diagnostics to colours for various commands.  Please do the non-bling-addicted world a favour and provide an option to not adorn the text....

Comment: _Please do the non-bling-addicted world a favour and provide an option to not adorn the text...._ Wish I could say that to developers who actually used ncurses/ANSI codes. :) The question came to be because some of my users aren't happy with piped out and want to retain colours. Thanks though, [R..](https://stackoverflow.com/users/379897/r) gave the answer I was looking for.

Comment: `openpty` is really not much work at all; it's about the same as calling `pipe` or `socketpair` except that you also need to think a little bit about if you want non-default termios modes.